# System for automating admin creation for any database

Tags: sql-server, database

For example I have a database, and want to have good automaticly generated admin for it. Is there software for this?

Comment: That will depend on your database. There are like gazillions of different databases out there: relational, non-relational, ...

Comment: You can use phpMyAdmin for example

Comment: Doesn't Microsoft's SQL Management Studio fit your needs?

Comment: If SSMS fits, then no one gonna pay thousand of dollars for building bussiness applications that most of the time, just fill data to database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your question is. What kind of admin tasks are you trying to automate?

The SQL Server Agent service can handle a lot of the scheduled aspect, as well as alerts for certain conditions. Policy Based Management can log and restrict certain database params across a single instance or multiple ones.

What more are you looking for? SSMS is the gui that sits on top of SQL Server for an easy implementation.

Comment: I mean like DynamicData, but without programming. Something that gives web interface to database quickly.